# How to check if the folder is a mounted folder?

Tags: linux, shell, mounted-volumes

I ussually use this shell script to check if the folder is a symlink or not :

```
if [ -L path ]
```

but in my case , the folder can be in 3 types : normal folder, symlink folder or mounted from my network (using mount_smbfs command) . How to check if the folder is a mounted one ?

Comment: There are no "folders" in *nix, there are directories. You can check whether a directory is a mounpoint with `mountpoint` command from util-linux. Or parse `/proc/self/mountinfo`

Comment: It might help if you explained why you need to tell whether a directory is also a mount point. That's a very unusual thing to do in a shell script and suggests you might be better served by a more powerful programming language than a shell script. Also, a pathname can refer to many other types of "files" such as unix domain sockets, character and block devices, named pipes, regular files, etcetera.

Comment: coreutils `df` has several non-standard options that may help such as: `-l`, `-t`, `-T`, `-x`